# hide/show information by checking a radio box in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

**HELLO, Please I wanna learn how can I make details div disappear just by checking a box (details) in javascript.**
Because I tried many ways, but no results::

```
  let myDetails = document.getElementById('myDetails');
  myDetails.checked = true;
  myDetails.addEventListener('change', togglemyDetails);
```

```
var togglemyDetails = function() {
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have a division where there are information, so by checking a box the section will disappear and by rechecking it it will appear

Comment: Why don't you use `<details>` and `<summary>`? See here: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-what-the-details-and-summary-elements-can-do

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need a div that you want to show and hide, and then two radio buttons in the same group. If you attach an onclick event to the two radio buttons, you can query which one is selected and then show or hide the original div accordingly:

```js
function toggle() {
  let toggled = document.querySelector("#show").checked;
  if (toggled)
    document.querySelector("#show-hide").style.visibility = "visible";
  else
    document.querySelector("#show-hide").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<div id="show-hide">Show and Hide</div>

<form>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="show" checked onclick="toggle()" name="group">
    <label for="show">Show</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="hide" onclick="toggle()" name="group">
    <label for="hide">Hide</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function () {
    // To execute on window load
    bindEvents();
}

function bindEvents() {
    // Bind event to check box for toggling details div
    document.querySelector(".toggleDetails")
        .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            // Get Details div using data-target attribute of checkbox
            // `e.target` here would be check box, the element on which this event has been triggerred
            var actionTarget = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute('data-target'));
            if (actionTarget) {
                if (e.target.checked) {
                    // Add class `hide` to details div when checkbox is checked
                    actionTarget.classList.add('hide');
                } else {
                    // Remove class `hide` from details div when checkbox is unchecked
                    actionTarget.classList.remove('hide');
                }
            }
        });
}
```

```css
/* Below css class will be used to hide when toggling */
.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
/* Just to highlight details div */
#details {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add Checkbox with data-target attribute pointing to the details div selector -->
<label><input type="checkbox" class="toggleDetails" data-target="#details"> Check to Hide Details</label>
<br/>
<!-- This is details div -->
<div id="details">
    Some text that of details to be shown when checkbox is clicked.
</div>
```